# Javascript to access Table data from different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Actually, I have a table format layout to display the timing information of clicnic operating Hours. I have an edit button in that table. Each row has an id property called *sysId*. So when I click edit, it redirects to the editing page. My editing page will look like the below image:

[image: img]

**Code to display Clinic Operating hours**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
       <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="sample_editable_1">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="display:none;">Id</th>
                                    <th>Day</th>

                                    <th>Morning Start Time</th>
                                    <th>Morning End Time</th>
                                    <th>Afternoon Start Time</th>
                                    <th>Afternoon End Time</th>
                                    <th>Evening Start Time</th>
                                    <th>Evening End Time</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
  <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.ProviderWrkHours)
               {
                   <tr>
                   <td style="display:none;">@item.SysID</td>
                   <td>@item.DayType</td>
                   <td contenteditable="true" style="text-align: center;">@item.MorningStartTime</td>
                   <td contenteditable="true" style="text-align: center;">@item.MorningEndTime</td>                                           @*      <td contenteditable="true">@item.MorningEndTime</td>*@
                    <td contenteditable="true" style="text-align: center;" @*id="editor"*@>@item.AfterNoonStartTime</td>
                   <td contenteditable="true">@item.AfterNoonEndTime</td>
                   <td contenteditable="true" style="text-align: center;">@item.EveningStartTime</td>
                   <td contenteditable="true">@item.EveningEndTime</td>
                   <td style="color:#0026ff">
                    @Html.ActionLink(" Edit", "UpdateTimings", "ClinicTimings", new { sysid = item.SysID }, new { @class = "fa fa-pencil" })
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
}
```

So how can I access the next sysid information (I mean next row information of table) when I click the right arrow using some javascript from the current page.

Comment: Please update your question with rendered `html` and also add `html` for your `arrow mark` element..

Comment: For arrow mark i am using livicon @GuruprasadRao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this code (not the exact one) in controller.

```
ViewBag.Next =  model.DBTable()
               .Select(m => m.ID)
               .OrderBy(m => m.ID)
               .Where(x=> x.Id > id)
               .FirstOrDefault()
               .ToString();

ViewBag.Previous =  model.DBTable()
               .Select(m => m.ID)
               .OrderByDesc(m => m.ID)
               .Where(x=> x.Id < id)
               .FirstOrDefault()
               .ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot @jaber